# Creating a central session object for different methods for Distributed Tensorflow

Tags: python, tensorflow, distributed-computing

I have been using distributed tensorflow for the past two days. I am running a distributed policy gradient agent which uses a custom `model` object which has separate methods like `def calculate_gradients` and `def update_params`. Each of these methods needs access to a `sess` object and do a `sess.run()` to do some calculations. I am defining a central supervisor object `self.sv = Supervisor()`. Within each method where I need to run a `sess.run()`, I have to separately call `with self.sv.managed_session(self.server.target) as sess`. Is there a way to avoid this? I think this really slows down my code.